# Trouble with UIImageView animations

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiimageview

I'm trying something rather simple for the first time, can anyone advise. I'm just trying to animate a bunch of photos with the image file name "IMG_2605.JPG"..."IMG_2650.JPG". Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    for (int i=2605; i<=2650;i++){
        NSString * temp=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"IMG_%d.JPG",i];

        NSLog(@"%@",temp); //this reveals correctly named image files

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:temp];
        self.animations.image=[UIImage imageNamed:temp]; //this works for static image
        [temp release];
        [self.images addObject:image];
    }

    self.animations.animationImages=self.images;
    [self.animations startAnimating]; // this does nothing
    NSLog(@"animating? %i",self.animations.isAnimating);// reports 0

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

UPDATE

I added some tests and in fact my images array is not getting filled up at all:

```
    NSLog(@"size of images: %d",[self.images count]);// reports zero

    for (id key in self.images){
        UIImage *test=key;
        NSLog(@"hello");// not a dern thing gets NSLogged
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this issue; it was in fact unrelated to anything i noted above, but rather a simple oversight on my `images` object.